# Merge object with Vuejs and Axios

Tags: arrays, object, vue.js, axios

I have two objects obtained from an axios.get and a fetch from an rss feed and the result is something like that:
[Two Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXjBX.jpg)

Objects have fields with different names but with the same meaning. For example: Title and Full_name refer to the name of the object.

Currently i have this configuration:

```
Obj1 = {title: "Main text 1", body: "text text 1"},
       {title: "Main text 2", body: "text text 2"};
Obj2 = {full_name: "Main Text 3", description: "text text 3"};
```

I would like to get an object like this:

```
Obj3= {name: "Main text 1", desc: "text text 1"},
      {name: "Main text 2", desc: "text text 2"};
      {name: "Main Text 3", desc: "text text 3"};
```

Currently I am using this code:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                obj1: {},
                obj2: {} 
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.axios
                .get('https://url.com')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.obj1 = response.data;
                  });
            fetch('https://url2.com')
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((response) => {
                    this.obj2 = response.items; 
                });
        } 
    }
</script>
```

I tried these solutions has the result is always empty:

```
let merged = {...this.obj1, ...this.obj2};

var merged = Object.assign( {}, this.obj1, this.obj2);
```

Comment: in where you are executing `let merged = { ...` ? Make sure you are executing this after getting the api response

Comment: In a function contained in "methods"  that is executed by "created".

Comment: so, the problem is your code `var merged = Object.assign( {}, this.obj1, this.obj2);` is executing before updating `obj1 or obj2` by API response. Added an answer using [`watchers`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code `var merged = Object.assign( {}, this.obj1, this.obj2);` is executing before updating `obj1 or obj2` by API response.

You can [**watch**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) `obj1` & `obj2`. Update the `merged` object when any of `obj1` or `obj2` is changed.

```js
<template>
  <div>Merged Object: {{ merged }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      obj1: {},
      obj2: {},
        merged: {}
      }
    },
  mounted() {
    this.axios
      .get('https://url.com')
      .then((response) => {
        this.obj1 = response.data;
      });
      fetch('https://url2.com')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((response) => {
          this.obj2 = response.items; 
        });
  },
  watch: { 
    // whenever obj1 changes, this function will run
    obj1(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.merged = Object.assign( {}, newVal, this.obj2);
    },

    // whenever obj2 changes, this function will run
    obj2(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.merged = Object.assign( {}, newVal, this.obj1);
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to your screenshot, `this.obj1` and `this.obj2` are **`Arrays`**

So you can merge them with the spread operator by using brackets to create a new array:

```js
let merged = [...this.obj1, ...this.obj2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Array Name as

```
var newArray[]
var Obj1 = {title: "Main text 1", body: "text text 1"},
           {title: "Main text 2", body: "text text 2"};
var Obj2 = {full_name: "Main Text 3", description: "text text 3"};`enter newArray.Push(Obj1);
newArray.Push(Obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `map` the second response and then `concat` to the first one.

```
var concObject = obj1.concat( obj2.map( item => ({name: item.full_name, desc: item.description}) ) )
```

NB: From your example `obj1` and `obj2` are arrays.